# Programming applications for Excel

Tags: .net, excel, vba, ms-office

As Excel is a great front-end UI, I want to build an application in Excel for interactive data analysis on our datasets.

On one side we can visualize the dataset or part of it using Excel. On the other hand, we can input some parameters and do sophislicated calculation and generate results.

I know that Excel is programable in VBA. The only BASIC I know is GW-BASIC. I'd more like to program in a C family language, also for performance's sake.

Could some suvery someone programming paradiams in Excel for me to choose? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a couple of books. The dog-eared ones on my shelf are

VB & VBA in a Nutshell, Paul Lomax, O'Reilley. The only VBA Reference Manual in print.

Excel 2007 VBA Programmers Reference, John Green et al, Wrox. My #1 recommendation. I don't know what I would have done without it.

And stick around here. Unlike MSDN's VBA forum, people here are really helpful, especially if it's an "interesting" problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Excel Developer Center on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905411.aspx) and [Excel Solutions with Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/dd162436.aspx) for a starting point.